# Partial differential equation with chain rule

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Problem statement:

Consider the PDE: $x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, (x,y)\neq (0,0) $

Determine all solutions to the equation of the form

$f(x,y)=g(r)$ where $r= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

My progress:

Now $f(x,y)=g(r)=g(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ and so the partial derivatives are:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=g'(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=g'(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Now our PDE will become:

$\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+\frac{y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} $

And furthermore: $x^2+y^2=1$ which is an equation for a circle at origo. So how did I end up wrong?

Comment: What did you do with $g'(r)$? The idea of this homework is that you transform a PDE for $f$ into a ODE for $g$.

Comment: Alright, I will give it a new try but I've red about transform a PDE to ODE but I wasn't paying enough attention apparently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the OP has answered the question himself, I just want to add the general solution of this PDE can be obtained via the [method of characteristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics). For that one converts the PDE in an ODE along the characteristic line. The system of ODE which needs to be solved reads
$$\frac{dx}{ds} = x, \frac{dy}{ds} = y, \frac{df}{ds}= \frac{1}{r}; $$
where $s$ parameterizes the characteristic line.

The general solution for $x$ and $y$ is given by
$$\tag{1}x= x_0 e^{s},y=y_0 e^{s};$$
thus we have $$\frac{df}{ds} = \frac{e^{-s}}{\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}} $$
which is solved by
$$f= f_0(y_0/x_0) - \frac{e^{-s}}{\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}}$$
where $f_0$ depends on the characteristic  line via $y_0/x_0$.
Using (1) to eliminate $x_0$ and $y_0$, we obtain
$$f= f_0(y/x) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
with an arbitrary function $f_0$.

Answer (score 2):

I actually solved it myself:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=g'(r)\frac{x}{r}$ and

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=g'(r)\frac{y}{r}$

This gives: $g'(r)\frac{x^2+y^2}{r}=\frac{1}{r} \Rightarrow rg'(r)=\frac{1}{r}$

With solution: $g(r)=C-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$